# PC won't boot from flash drive after computer hibernated (grub on hdd corrupt too)

Tags: hard-drive, boot, grub, file-corruption, filesystem-corruption

I had 3 OS installed: Windows 7 , Fedora 17 and Mageia 2 in my Acer Aspire 4253 laptop.

I deleted the partition of Mageia and my grub got corrupted.
I didn't have an installation DVD of either Win7 or Fedora, so I used super grub 2 from a flash drive to boot my laptop.

Then one day when I was using Windows 7, my battery was critically low and laptop got hibernated. When I plugged in the power and restarted the `press F2, f12` prompts were missing and the flash drive is not getting detected after POST.

What can I do now to boot my PC?

Comment: Are you sure your hardware is OK? Are you able to get into BIOS?